# Should we have a canonical certification list?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, list-questions

There seem to be a few questions concerning Software Development Certification(s) that people want to get.

Since quite a few people have hired software developers and quite a few more people have interviewed for the positions wouldn't be better to come up with a list of certifications that people actually look at and would give a salary bump then just suggesting based on individual questions?

Granted this question is probably better for [IT Careers & Training](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12887/it-careers-training), but since this site is not yet public these questions are far more likely to come to this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking "what certification should I get?" doesn't really fit with the Stack Exchange model of Q&A: strangers telling people how they should plan their career is always a bad idea and usually too localized to the asker's specific circumstances.

One way to make such questions not too localized, or at least more general, is to create a list of certifications, like you suggest, to let people decide on their own which ones seem interesting. Canonical lists do have their uses, but they're an exception to the rule, and generally reserved for [a last-ditch effort](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/8) to try and save a question.

There are a few problems with trying to use lists as the "go-to" method to solve a question quality problem like this:

- It's untenable for us to create a canonical list of every single certification a person can get, and more importantly, provide a reason why it's on the list (instead of just adding a link)
- What criteria are used to generate the list is an open question, making the list dubious in quality or accuracy
- While everybody likes the idea of lists, very few people take the non-trivial amount of effort to actively maintain the list
- Lists are still [outside the Stack Exchange style of Q&A](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Instead of telling people what they should do, or providing a long list of stuff and telling them "have fun!", it's almost always going to be better to ask questions that informs someone how to find and decide for themselves. Stuff like:

- How do I go about identifying whether a certification is  useful in my line of work?
- [Are certifications worth it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/44/8)

Comment: I think [this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3102/41381) is an elegant solution for providing lists for commonly asked questions

Comment: I'll accept the answer although it seems to me that the list of the certifications that people actually consider when hiring someone for software engineer/developer position might be very short.

Answer (score 3):

To add to [what Mark said](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3109/4), consider writing a tag excerpt and starting a tag wiki for the [certification tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/certification/info). Both are currently empty. Perhaps organize a list by topic area, write a short description including the name of the certification, who sponsors/offers it, and provide a link to the official website to learn more. That seems like it would add plenty of value.

Comment: Took your advice on tag wiki.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would a good topic for the blog. At least until IT Careers or the Workplace launches.

Comment: I don't know if this would be a good topic for the blog since it's not just one man's opinion with comments but I envisioned a more collaborative effort.  Otherwise it just might become a flamewar of this is good and that one is bad.  I for example don't look at any certifications on the resumes(CVs)

Comment: I don't know how appropriate it is for The Workplace - it's about software development, and doesn't apply to other professions. IT Careers, maybe.