# Blacklist [software-engineering]

Tags: support, status-completed, stci, tag-blacklist

[software-engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering) was recently cleaned up, through the [Structured Tag Cleanup Initiative](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3263/structured-tag-cleanup-software-engineering). Obviously since we [already identified it as a tag that doesn't belong](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3094/25936) and we went through the trouble of cleaning it up, there is no point in keeping it around anymore.

Can we please kill it now?

Comment: I am okay with this.  I went through most of the questions listed in the latest cleanup initiative and couldn't find a way to heroically edit any of them.  They are all unsalvageable in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been blacklisted. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's safe to kill it now.