# Structured Tag Cleanup: [software-development]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, posse, stci

> **Related:**
>
> [Request for comment: structured tag cleanups](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/request-for-comment-structured-tag-cleanups)
>
> [Structured Tag Cleanup — Call for proposals #1](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/structured-tag-cleanup-call-for-proposals-1)

Welcome to the third structured tag cleanup!

Based on the voting in the [call for proposals](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/structured-tag-cleanup-call-for-proposals-1), the second round goes to the [software-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) tag, with 282 current questions.

The tag has been renamed to [stci-software-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-software-development), which hopefully should prevent people from adding any more questions to it.

#### Ground rules

The goal of this cleanup is to systematically clean up the software development tag without causing disruption to the rest of the site. Your job, should you choose to accept it, is:

- Review the [deletion candidates](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3357/25936) below and see if there's a way to save any of the questions before they go gently into that good night through [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits). At the end of the clean up period, any questions not sufficiently improved will be deleted.
- Review the [merge candidates](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3356/25936) to see if can be merged into one question. If they shouldn't be, revise the questions to demonstrate how it's not in any way like the question it's been duplicated to.
- Review the [closure candidates](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3355/25936) list to see if you agree with what others have identified as being out of the site's scope. If you agree, vote to close. If you don't agree, use [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits) to address the problems the question has and bring it back into scope.
- Review the [currently open questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstci-software-development%5D+closed%3A0&submit=search) and see which ones do not fit our site scope. Vote to close them and add them to the closure candidates list.
- Improve the leftover questions by copyediting, fixing spelling, flow, adding clearer titles, etc. while replacing the `stci-software-development` tag with something more meaningful<sup>1</sup>:

  - [web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) for questions relating to web development,
  - [mobile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile) for questions relating to mobile development,
  - [architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) for questions relating to system level architecture, documenting architecture, view models, architectural quality, and product line development.
  - [design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) for questions relating to software design.
  - [documentation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) for questions about documentation.
  - [requirements](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requirements) for questions about requirements engineering and documenting requirements.
  - [testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) for questions about unit, integration, smoke, and system testing using white box or black box techniques.
  - [maintenance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) for questions about maintaining legacy software systems.
  - [quality](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quality) for questions about process quality, product quality, code quality, or measuring the quality of any of these.
  - [education](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) for questions about formal education, self-teaching, and self-improvement as a software developer.
  - [metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metrics) for questions about software metrics.
  - [patterns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patterns) for questions on design patterns.
  - [agile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile) for questions on agile methodologies.
  - [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) for questions on project management.

  ...and other, more specific tags as needed.
- Finally, and this is perhaps the most important of all the rules: **do not just remove the stci-software-engineering tag without improving the question and its answers.**

#### End date

This round of cleanups will end on **Sunday, April 8th at 04:00 UTC.** At that time, all the default actions will be done: deletions, merges, closures, and such. If [stci-software-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-software-development) is not empty by then, it'll be renamed back to [software-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) and be saved for later rounds of cleanups.

If it is empty, we will move on to getting it blacklisted.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> These are (mostly) the same suggestions as for the [software-engineering] cleanup - I felt they make sense for [software-development] and couldn't find any other tags that would be common candidates for [software-development] questions. If you have suggestions, please edit them in.</sub>

Comment: If you have questions on the process, please read [Request for comment: structured tag cleanups](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/request-for-comment-structured-tag-cleanups). Objections / suggestions and every other comment on the process itself should be posted there (as a comment to the answers or a new answer), not here.

Comment: I thought we had until the 8th? I had planned on trying to save [Is it normal to think about a design problem for days with no code written?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118962/1130) from deletion this weekend

Comment: @Rachel Yes, my mistake, I mixed up the dates. I've undeleted that one, but it's an extremely "not constructive" question.

Comment: Thanks :) Will it stay not deleted? Or do you plan on deleting it again on Sunday?

Comment: @Rachel No promises, I'll have to see your edits first, but I wouldn't have undeleted it if I was set on deleting it again, that would be cruel even by my standards. Ping me in chat on Sunday, I'll probably be around (even if you don't see me in chat) so we can go through the question together.

Comment: I don't have time to talk about it this weekend... my out-of-town house guests stayed an extra day and today is Easter so is going to be spent cooking and with family. If you're available Monday, perhaps we could talk about it?

Comment: @Rachel Oh, don't worry about it, no specific time limit here. But there's little that can be done there to re-open it, it's off topic (not unique to programmers) and not constructive (if it's normal or not is polling for people's opinions) at the same time... But of course if you can convince four others...  Anyways ping me in chat when you have time, so we can go through it together.

Answer (score 1):

#### Closure candidates

Add any question you find while combing the [[stci-software-development] tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstci-software-development%5D+closed%3A0) that does not meet the site's scope and fell through the cracks. Review any existing question to see if it does need to be closed or can be saved by a [heroic edit](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits).

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139201/how-to-become-very-strong-in-middleware-java-coding
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140582/writing-drivers-for-a-printer
3. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80575/when-to-remove-programmer-access-in-dev-sandbox
4. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29167/need-repository-layout-references
5. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32785/first-time-application-where-to-start
6. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40235/development-cost-for-ipad-application-and-on-going-maintenance
7. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47993/best-software-development-methodology-environment-for-fresh-graduates
8. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57828/your-software-problem-solution-approach
9. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61891/how-and-where-to-organize-a-team-to-make-a-website
10. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65600/using-personal-blog-as-well-as-software-company
11. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76108/decisions-affecting-software-development
12. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88198/advice-on-how-to-understand-in-general-and-in-practice-it-infrastructure
13. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126751/what-technologies-and-what-languages-should-i-choose-to-make-web-application-por
14. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134060/is-there-a-snippets-program-that-allows-for-tab-entry-of-variables-across-the-ma
15. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/to-develop-a-front-end-web-application-with-tablets-in-mind-or-not
16. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134940/can-a-company-deny-that-you-teach-people-how-to-use-a-software-under-mit-license
17. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25733/where-can-i-get-people-to-test-my-software-for-free
18. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43113/looking-software-for-making-an-animated-cartoon-to-present-a-new-application-sce
19. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50427/books-on-software-development-is-code-complete-good-or-should-i-read-something
20. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66902/project-management-and-team-connecting-tools-for-developers
21. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136015/standard-c-tools-frameworks-in-2012
22. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43214/how-do-you-educate-your-teammates-without-seeming-condescending-or-superior
23. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136441/can-anybody-recommend-an-application-for-laying-out-algorithms-on-a-mac
24. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49457/learning-to-program-in-the-modern-era
25. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64875/what-are-your-examples-of-great-companies-with-work-environments
26. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60906/productivity-and-communication-in-teamwork-vs-individual-concentration-and-list
27. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46429/is-porting-a-windows-application-to-mac-worth-it
28. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43113/looking-software-for-making-an-animated-cartoon-to-present-a-new-application-sce
29. [Can a freelancer use agile development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38140/can-a-freelancer-use-agile-development)
30. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/developing-for-research-vs-developing-a-product
31. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22224/recommended-bounty-site
32. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97658/how-do-i-host-a-project-on-github-or-sourceforge
33. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58593/how-much-knowledge-do-you-need-to-call-yourself-a-programmer
34. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86170/security-programming-jobs
35. [What is the correlation between the quality of the software development process and the quality of the product?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60694/what-is-the-correlation-between-the-quality-of-the-software-development-process)
36. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61698/remote-job-opportunities-for-software-developers
37. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92696/how-to-grow-after-failing-in-a-software-development-shop
38. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/90559/why-dont-modern-software-developers-follow-the-advice-of-alan-cooper-and-jef-ra
39. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101725/is-there-any-tv-channel-for-developers
40. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36317/what-are-some-good-online-tech-talks
41. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57987/which-db-should-i-use-for-my-newbie-program
42. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58584/how-can-i-change-my-career-from-windows-server-admin-to-software-developer
43. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94197/how-to-i-build-a-sudoku-solver-software-using-c
44. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66286/as-a-developer-which-version-of-windows-has-everything-needed-for-standard-pro
45. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95336/what-are-the-research-components-involved-in-a-software-product-development
46. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72451/sources-of-information-for-flight-hotel-reservation-recommendation-sites
47. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115509/what-are-some-group-oriented-project-development-sites
48. add questions here

Answer (score 1):

#### Merge candidates

Please review these questions closed as duplicates to see if they can be merged. If they shouldn't be merged, please use [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits) to clarify why the questions aren't duplicates of each other and vote to reopen.

- [Is cowboy programming a senior approach?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83167/is-cowboy-programming-a-senior-approach) → [Frankly, do you prefer Cowboy coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7217/frankly-do-you-prefer-cowboy-coding)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102348/my-lead-does-not-co-operate-may-be-lack-of-knowledge-or-unwillingness → [How do you tell if advice from a senior developer is bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78547/how-do-you-tell-if-advice-from-a-senior-developer-is-bad)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64275/standalone-developers-whats-are-your-methods-of-development → [Design and Development Methodologies for the single developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63048/design-and-development-methodologies-for-the-single-developer)
- [Why there is a testing team?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103095/why-there-is-a-testing-team) → [Why to let / not let developers test their own work](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77146/why-to-let-not-let-developers-test-their-own-work)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101602/can-i-be-too-old-to-be-just-a-programmer → [How old is "too old"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-old-is-too-old)
- [What is a good way to refactor a large, terribly written code base by myself?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125435/what-is-a-good-way-to-refactor-a-large-terribly-written-code-base-by-myself) → [Techniques to re-factor garbage and maintain sanity?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66438/techniques-to-re-factor-garbage-and-maintain-sanity)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105862/online-code-reviews → https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104975/website-for-code-review
- [How to protect own software from copying](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128044/how-to-protect-own-software-from-copying)  → [How do you prevent the piracy of your software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10340/how-do-you-prevent-the-piracy-of-your-software)

Answer (score -1):

#### Deletion candidates

Please review these questions to see which can be saved through [heroic edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/whats-all-this-about-heroic-edits) and reopened. If no improvement would make them on topic, vote to delete if you have the reputation.

- [Is it normal to think about a design problem for days with no code written?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118962/is-it-normal-to-think-about-a-design-problem-for-days-with-no-code-written)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97484/why-are-bad-developers-offended-by-flaws-in-their-code
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125383/how-to-get-rogues-to-use-good-programming-practices